# Does _NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN imply _NET_WM_STATE_SKIP_TASKBAR

Tags: show-hide, x11, standards-compliance, window-managers, window-management

After switching from KDE to XFCE, I notice that the boinc manager window will remain visible in the task bar as a minimized window when I close the window. On KDE (as far as I remember), closing the window had the effect of completely hiding it, while a system tray icon remained to control the application. I guess that's the intended behavior in any case.

According to `xprop`, the window has

```
WM_STATE(WM_STATE):
                window state: Iconic
                icon window: 0x10a3f90
_NET_WM_STATE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN
```

The state atom [`_NET_WM_STATE_SKIP_TASKBAR`](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/ar01s05.html) which would explicitely indicate omission from the task bar is not included in that list.

Now I want to figure out where to correct this. Should I fix `xfce-panel` to skip windows which have hidden state? Or should I try make the window state include `_NET_WM_STATE_SKIP_TASKBAR`? The code path for the hiding the window appears to be via wxWidgets and its `wxWindowGTK::Show` method to `gtk_widget_hide` to [`XWithdrawWindow`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/xmapwindow), so perhaps `xfwm4` should react and add that atom?

Are there any official documentations of how hiding a window is supposed to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN` should be set by the window manager, not the application. In particular, *[all minimized windows](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/ar01s05.html)* should have `_NET_WM_STATE` set to `_NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN`. By no means does this state imply `_NET_WM_STATE_SKIP_TASKBAR`.